# Angular 7 Authorization Not working correctly

Tags: oauth, angular7

I'm working on implementing Authentication I am using an interceptor to do this with. However, I'm getting an error.

> "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Below is the interceptor code.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{


    constructor(@Inject('IAuthService') private authService:IAuthService) {          
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):


    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if(this.authService.isLoggedIn){
            req = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authService.token}`)
              });
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

And this is shown in the request that it is adding the token to the 
[image: Request Headers]:

So I can make the request from Postman and return the correct data.

Just so you can see the full error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse:
>   {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized","url":"http://localhost/Invoicing/api/users/settings/getTableColumns/leads-list","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http
>   failure response for
>   http://localhost/Invoicing/api/users/settings/getTableColumns/leads-list:
>   401 Unauthorized","error":{"message":"Authorization has been denied
>   for this request."}}
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, which was that I had added the interceptor to `app.module.ts` and I needed to add it to every module that the service using it is in.

I hope this helps someone else.